# Losing 'FormattedID' link after applying style changes

Tags: javascript, rally

I have a rallygrid object set up with the following settings for columnCfgs:

```
columnCfgs: [
    'FormattedID',
    'Name',
    'PlanEstimate'
]
```

Which gives me a nice formatted link to the UserStory in the "FormattedID" field. The problem is, I don't like the way the columns are laid out on the page so I changed the FormattedID column to:

```
{ text: 'ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', width: 60 }
```

This gives me the correct column spacing but the field text is no longer linked directly to the user story it references. How can I alter the column width, but also keep the nice formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the FormattedIDTemplate class to properly format the link:

```
{
    text: 'ID',
    width: 60,
    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
}
```

Note that the FormattedIDTemplate class is marked as private, and it's interface may change in future versions of the sdk.