# How to make a User story ID act as a link in the custom report in rally

Tags: extjs, rally, extjs5, code-rally

I have created a report which displays user story ID, name of the story, current kanban state of the story and total number of days the story stayed in each state as shown below using extjs. But i want the ID to act as a link in the report that is when clicked, it should display the information of story just like how when user story is clicked in the kanban board,it displays that story information.

```
var gridbox = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                    store: data,
                    columnLines: true,
                    columns: [
                    {
                        text: 'Formatted ID', 
                        dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Name', 
                        dataIndex: 'Name',
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Current Kanban State', 
                        dataIndex: 'c_Kanban',

                    },
                     {
                     text: 'Ready', 
                     dataIndex: 'ready',
                     },
                     {
                     text: 'In Development',
                     dataIndex: 'indev',
                     componentCls:'columnstyle',
                     },
                     {
                     text: 'Development Done',
                     dataIndex: 'devdone',
                     }

                ],
                 viewConfig: {
                    stripeRows: true
                } 

            });
            this.add(gridbox);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're not using the [Rally.ui.Grid](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.grid.Grid) component in the AppSDK?  That should wire up the correct FormattedID renderer for you, in addition to having consistent styling with the rest of the product:

```
this.add({
    xtype: 'rallygrid',
    columnCfgs: [
        'FormattedID',
        'Name',
        {
            text: 'Current Kanban State', 
            dataIndex: 'c_Kanban'
        },
        'Ready',
        {
            text: 'In Development',
            dataIndex: 'indev',
            componentCls:'columnstyle',
        },
        {
            text: 'Development Done',
            dataIndex: 'devdone',
        }
    ],
    enableEditing: false,
    showRowActionsColumn: false,
    store: data,
    columnLines: true,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    } 
});
```

Comment: ..@Kyle Morse i am using grid panel to get functions like sortable, lockable,locked. I need to make column headers fixed and few columns fixed when moved horizontal same like locking grid example: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/example/grid/locking-grid.html

Comment: So can you tell me how to do with the grid to get the link? @Kyle Morse

Comment: ah.  The rally grid just extends the Ext.Grid.Panel, so most of that stuff should still work I would think...  But anyway I'll try to dig up the code to wire up that FormattedID renderer...

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679297/losing-formattedid-link-after-applying-style-changes/11723789#11723789

Comment: i used your above link code. but still its not working.The link is not formed.
var grid=Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
 xtype: 'rallygrid',
    store: data,
    columnLines: true,
 id: 'grid',
    columns: [{
        text: 'Formatted ID', 
  dataIndex: 'FormattedID',
  align: 'center',
  locked:true,
  componentCls:'style',
  xtype: 'templatecolumn',
  tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')  
    },                                                                                                               @Kyle Morse